# Check if in Integrated Pipeline Mode

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

Is it possible to check if our code is executing in Integrated Pipeline Mode or not?

There are some ASP.NET class properties that only work in Integrated Pipeline Mode, and I want to avoid raising an exception if there is a way to test if our code is executing in that environment or not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're looking for the [`HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline.aspx).